# Error while restoring analysis service db file

Tags: ssas

When i am trying to attach Analysis service db file (MDX Step-by-Step.abf)

by running the below commnand.

C:\Microsoft Press\MDX SBS\Setup\Analysis Services\Mdx Step-by-Step.abf

MDX Step-by-Step

IgnoreSecurity

I am getting below error.

> Executing the query ... The following system error occurred:  The
>   system cannot find the path specified. . Backup and restore errors:
>   File 'C:\Microsoft Press\MDX SBS\Setup\Analysis Services\Mdx
>   Step-by-Step.abf' specified in Restore command is damaged or is not an
>   AS backup file. Execution complete

Comment: Is the path specified as seen from the Analysis Services server engine, or as seen from your client machine? Did you give the user running the Analysis Services service the right to access this path? (By default, this user can only access the data and backup directory within the Analysis Services installation directory.)

Comment: I have attached the Analysis db by correcting the path.Now i am facing the issue when i am running the MDX command. 'It says the MDX cube either does not exist or not have been processed.'

Comment: This probably means - as it states - that the measure group/partition that contains the measure you access is not processed. You should then possibly change the data source property of the cube to point to a valid relational database containing the source data as configured in the data source view of the cube, and then process the database, cube, partition, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This response/answer is for the users who land here while seeking solution to same kind of problems.

First issue mentioned in main post is related to path of '.abf'. It should be path on the machine, where Analysis Server is installed. Specially not on user's local machine, from where most of users connect through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) client application.

Second issue mentioned in comments is related to type of project. '.abf' extension is for tabular analysis services project rather than multi-dimensional data warehouse project. MDX queries are for multidimensional projects, whereas DAX queries are for tabular projects.